# Is JavaScript caching calls to Object.keys() in functional filter(), every() etc.?

Tags: javascript

Does it influence performance if I cache a call to `Object.keys()` in a variable when repeteadly checking it's content inside `every()`, `filter()`, `any()` etc. functions ? Does the JS engine perform inline caching in this case?

```js
X = {/*...*/};
t = [/*...*/];
f = key => {/*...*/}; // somehow transforms keys of X

// we want to check if all elements of t are the transformed keys of X
keys = Object.keys(X).map(f);
result = t.every(a=>keys.includes(a)); // <──────── is this faster than this ?
result = t.every(a=>Object.keys(X).map(f).includes(a)); // <──────────────┘

// same with filtering etc.
t = t.filter(a => !Object.keys(X).includes(a)); // discarding elements from t that are not keys in X
```

The answer will influence my coding practice, I'd much rather use the second, more compact version, because it can be used in a one-line lambdas and is easier to look at without jumping to definitions.

Comment: In general, Javascript will *never* cache anything that isn't guaranteed to be stable. The contents of `X` *could* change between calls to `Object.keys`, so caching this operation could lead to incorrect results.

Comment: FWIW, this could be written like `t.every(k => X.hasOwnProperty(k))` in the first place…!? You can directly test whether an object has a property, you don't need to extract all its keys into a list and then search the list. As such, most of these kinds of questions are moot to begin with and just a sign of a bad algorithm.

Comment: In my opinion, it should be cached otherwise it can be caused the wrong result for cases that content changes dynamically. Let say, you have an array and you search something in the array. if it caches your searches, it will return the wrong result when the array content updated. This is just my theory, I don't know right answer. I am going to follow thread as well.

Comment: Yes that's a good point: caching introduces a kind of complexity that can be a breeding ground for hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: It's not about bragging about how short the code is, but how much easier it is for me to maintain and read that code. @deceze right, thx, the example was off the top of my head, but if I have to, for example, map the keys then it makes sense*

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan I think that if you try to change the collection while you are iterating over it in functional manner, then there is already something wrong with the design of the code. I live by this rule "functional=immutable, imperative=mutable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your code performs the operations many thousands of times, it won't matter. However making a function call (to `Object.keys()`) and in the process instantiating a new array will always use more resources than *not* doing that.

It's more important for your code to be understandable and maintainable than optimally composed in almost all cases.

It's also a really good idea to not rely on supposed optimization behaviors inside the JavaScript runtime(s).  Those may change. It's OK to simply trust that somebody maintaining the runtime has performance as their full-time job.

Comment: Well, "it's *somebody's* job to care about performance" isn't an excuse to write horribly inefficient Javascript code either though…

Comment: @deceze sure, but as always overall algorithmic quality is usually much more important. This sort of fine-grained finickiness is not often the correct path to good code anyway.